# Return False / Stop jQuery Function on click

Tags: jquery

I have function `Start()` that is fired on ready. When I click on `.ExampleClick`, I want to stop function `Start()` from running. Here is my example...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(function Start(){
      // Do Stuff on Ready
  });

  $(document).on("click",".ExampleClick",function() {
     // When this is fired, function Start() should stop running
  });

});
```

What is the best method to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You can't do this. At least not sanely.

Comment: How often does Start need to run? @Daniel, that's not entirely true. :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville -  It is done when the user loads the document. Quite often

Comment: @ElliotBonneville. you can't run two parallel functions at the same time!

Comment: Why do you have two nested `ready` handlers? How long does `Start` run? What is it doing? Is it running in a loop? If yes you can use a flag and `setTimeout`. You have to provide more information.

Comment: Like... how often? Ten times a second? Twenty? Once a second? I'm thinking Start() could have a setTimeout that calls iteself in the bottom that's only called if a certain boolean variable that reflects whether or not .ExampleClick has been clicked evaluates to false.

Comment: @Joe elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish and perhaps there's a different approach.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville When a user loads this page, function start() fires to check result records. The function stops on the last record. But if the user clicks .ExampleClick, then I would like start() to stop executing the loop.

Comment: Then you want something like @meager's answer, with a counter inside your looping function that'll keep track of which record you're on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `Start` is looping forever, your browser will hang. JavaScript functions cannot truly run in parallel. Assuming that `Start` is indeed some background process that is meant to loop forever, you'll need to re-think things so that it executes once and then schedules itself to execute again some point in the future, allowing other events to be handled.

Each time `Start` executes, it can examine some state maintained by the on-click handler to decide whether or not it should run and enqueue itself again:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var clicked = false;

  var Start = function () {
      if (clicked) return;

      // Do Stuff on Ready

      setTimeout(Start, 100);
  };

  Start();

  $(document).on("click",".ExampleClick",function() {
     // When this is fired, function Start() should stop running

     clicked = true;
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @meagar. This is helpful, though I do have a setTimeout to reschedule itself but I did not mention it in this post.

Comment: You are a savior. Found the exact solution. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a function you want to run repeatedly and then stop it when you click:

```
doStuff = function() {
    // stuff to do regularly
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    // run doStuff every 2 seconds
    var jobId = window.setInterval(doStuff, 2000);

    // store the job id in a jquery data object
    $('body').data("doStuffJobId", jobId);

    // set up click hander for css class Example Click
    $(".ExampleClick").click(function() {
        // get the job id
        var jobId = $('body').data("doStuffJobId");
        window.clearInterval(jobId);
    });

});
```

Comment: +1 `setInterval` is a better way of doing this than my `setTimeout` version.

Answer (score 2):

You could fudge something with a setinterval():

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  var intervalHolder;     

  $(function Start(){ 
      // Do Stuff on Ready
      intervalHolder = setInterval("myTimedFunction()",1000);
      // This runs "myTimedFunction()" every second
  }); 

  $(document).on("click",".ExampleClick",function() { 
     // When this is fired, function Start() should stop running 
     clearInterval(intervalHolder);
  }); 

}); 

function myTimedFunction() {
   // Do groovy things every second
};
```

It's a bit primative, but could be worked to acheive a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: as others pointed out, my previous solution was entirely wrong. I'm replacing it with the setInterval/clearInterval approach (for the sake of correctness - others have already pointed out better/similar solutions):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var start = setInterval(
        function Start(){
            // Do Stuff on Ready
        },
        someReasonableTimeFrame
    );

    $(document).on("click",".ExampleClick",function() {
        // When this is fired, function Start() should stop running
        clearInterval(start);
    });

});
```

Comment: The click event handler would never be executed (or even attached), because `Start` never terminates.

Comment: That isn't true! you can't have two methods run in the same time, it will never "get-out" of the `while`!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I had already noticed it and was fixing it.

Comment: Still incorrect. It doesn't matter how you call `Start`, it will *never return* and your on-click handler will never been bound.

Comment: @FelixKling lol you're right! edited again, hope it's fixed now (though I think meagar already gave a sactisfatory [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9792302/520779), more suitable to the OP according to his feedback in the comments below it)

Comment: Nevermind that, it wont work either... @meagar thanks for pointing out that JavaScript functions can't run in parallel, I didn't really know that! I'll edit it again just for the sake of correctness, but your answer is really the best one.